# When it make sense to replace "class_name obj_name = func()" by "class_name obj_name{func()}"?

Tags: c++, assign, initializer-list

In a code I see the following construct:

```
const class_name obj_name{func()};
```

func() return an object of the class called `class_name`. So, I wonder why not to use the following construction:

```
const class_name obj_name = func();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const class_name obj_name{func()};
```

By writing the above, the author is trying to follow *uniform initialization syntax* (introduced by C++11), so as to avoid problems caused by *vexing parse* and *most vexing parse*, into which even experienced programmers get trapped accidently. He is trying to inculcate the best practice into his brain so that he doesn't get trapped into the said parsing issues occasionally as explained below.

Consider this,

```
struct X { /*....*/ }; // some class

struct Y 
{
    Y();
    Y(int i);
    Y(X x);
};
```

Now one can write this:

```
Y y(100); // declare an object y of type Y
```

that invokes the second constructor, which is fine. So far, so fine!

But accidently one even write this:

```
Y y();
```

(mistakenly) thinking that it invokes the default constructor. But the fact is that it doesn't invoke the default constructor. It instead declares a function `y` which takes no argument, and returns `Y`.  That is called **vexing parse** in C++.

Likewise, one can write this (accidently),

```
Y y(X());
```

thinking that it invokes the third constructor passing an object of type `X` which is created on the fly. Again, it is wrong. It instead declares a function `y` which takes a function pointer (of type function which takes nothing and return `X`) and return `Y`. It is called **most vexing parse** in C++.

So uniform initialization syntax avoids all such issues, you can write this:

```
Y y1{};      // invokes 1st constructor
Y y2{100};   // invokes 2nd constructor
Y y3{X{}};   // invokes 3rd constructor
```

and following the same syntax,

```
Y { function_call() }; 

const class_name obj_name { func() }; // taken from your question!
```

That is *uniform* and certainly best practice, isn't?

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As of C++11 the [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) feature was introduced which provides several ways to initialize types.

In this case, both syntaxes will call the `class_name(class_name const&)` copy constructor (if one exists). Therefore there's no real difference. It just a matter of preference.

It is to note that the `{}` syntax don't always behave like in this case: if there is an initialization_list constructor of the appropriate type, that constructor is used, **otherwise** the class elements are initialized using the appropriate constructor.

In cases where the *Most Vexing Parse* principle (if it can possibly be interpreted as a function prototype, then it will be) strikes you are required to use either one of the two to tell the compiler that the following is not a function prototype:

```
typename class_name obj_name(func());
class_name obj_name { func() };
```